# Method parameters are being separated into new lines

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, resharper, stylecop

Ever since I installed StyleCop, ReSharper has been forcing method parameters on seperate lines regardless of my settings.

An example is:

```
return this._context.ContentItems
    .Join(this._context.SiteSchedules, ci => ci.ID, sc => sc.ContentItemID, 
        (ci, sc) => new {SiteSchedule = sc, ContentItem = ci})
    .Join(this._context.Blogs, o => o.ContentItem.ID, b => b.ContentItemID, 
        (o, b) => new { o.ContentItem, o.SiteSchedule, Blog = b })
```

Gets reformated to:

```
return this._context.ContentItems
    .Join(
        this._context.SiteSchedules, 
        ci => ci.ID, 
        sc => sc.ContentItemID, 
        (ci, sc) => new { SiteSchedule = sc, ContentItem = ci })
     .Join(
         this._context.Blogs, 
         o => o.ContentItem.ID, 
         b => b.ContentItemID, 
         (o, b) => new { o.ContentItem, o.SiteSchedule, Blog = b })
```

Searching online I found an option to `keep existing line breaks`, have turned that on but it still formats it.  I have tried setting the `Wrap formal parameters` to both `simple wrap` and the default `chop if long` but none of this work.  Is there another option that would interfere with the layout in this manner from either StyleCop or ReSharper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the setting that was affecting line breaks.  Apparently with the StyleCop installed, I had to uncheck the settings `Code Editing | C# | Line Breaks and Wrapping | Line Wrapping -> Wrap long lines`